# Using HTML tags in value attribute of xf:output

Tags: orbeon

I need to change the value of xf:output element dynamically based on another input field.
For this I'm using *concat* method and setting the value attribute like this

```
value="concat('The price is ', instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/my-price, ' euros.')"
```

where my-price is the control where the user can enter some amount which I want to display in the output control.

As a result I would get something like this "The price is 100 euros.", but now I should add some styling to one part of this sentence e.g. "The price is **100 euros.**".
Is it possible to use html tags within the value attribute of output control, or is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following:

```
<xf:output
    mediatype="text/html"
    value="
        concat(
            'The price is &lt;b&gt;',
            100,
            '&lt;/b&gt; euros.'
        )
"/>
```